# create final deb file from multiple deb files

Tags: debian

I have a packages deb file with all dependencies deb file.

Is it possible to create a final deb file (one file) using all. Say for example `firefox.deb` has 10 dependencies in another `.deb` file. So there is an order to install all the dependencies then afterwards `firefox.deb`. May I create a `fullFirefox.deb` file which automatically maintain everything ? I do not have the source, just the deb files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It *is* possible, but you'll likely run in several issues. First, each package has it's own pre- and post-installation scripts and dependencies in the control file. Even if you make a package provide the contained packages using the `Provides` field, future upgrades may ruin your God package:

1. You install your God package which provides a lot packages
2. One of the packages are being updated, like `libpango1.0-0`
3. If you upgrade that package, your God package will be removed. If there are any dependencies on it, apt-get has an unresolvable conflict.

So, it's better not to create a God package, but install each package separately. If you need to install software offline, see [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/974/6969)

How to create a God package (not recommended):

1. Create a temporary directory, e.g. "~/godpackage" and `cd` into it
2. Extract each .deb file using `dpkg -x filename.deb .`
3. Extract the control, postrm, ..., files using `dpkg --control filename.deb tmpdeb`. A new directory will be created, named `tmpdeb`. Adjust the control files like changing the name to avoid conflicts later. When done, move / merge the tmpdeb directory with the DEBIAN directory (create if needed). Repeat it for each deb file
4. Go away from the directory: `cd ..`
5. Create the new debfile from `~/godpackage` and store the newly created .deb file in the current directory: `dpkg-deb --build ~/godpackage .`

Comment: thank you Lekensteyn. Your information is very helpful for me. Will you please explain what does "When done, move / merge the tmpdeb directory with the DEBIAN directory (create if needed)" mean?

Comment: A package should have a DEBIAN directory containing the control file and optionally postinst, postrm, preinst, prerm and some others. All libraries run `ldconfig` in their postinst script, so that can easily be merged. It gets more difficult if a post-installation script depends on a configured package. Finally, it makes debugging much harder, if one action in the {pre,post}{rm,inst} scripts fail, it'll quit or lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: I love the official terminology used: "God package"